# How to use the lasso in Space Pirate Trainer?

Tags: space-pirate-trainer

I'm playing on the Oculus Quest. When I reach back with my right hand I get a lasso alt weapon. I can use it to move enemies, but not hurt them - so what's the point of the lasso and how to best utilize it?

Answer (score 2):

The lasso does have ways of harming enemies. Firstly, you can slam the enemies into the ground (or each other) to destroy or damage them.

Secondly, if you imagine it to be a sword-like shape, the "blade" is a laser cutter. 
If you use the lasso to pull in the enemy (point, hold trigger, yoink! - *think Ghostbusters*) you can then slice the incoming enemy into pieces.

[Here is a video of lasso gameplay](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zOyZQ2zJGUg). There isn't much cutting that I can see, though the player does seem to attempt it a few times.

To be honest, I don't think the lasso is a particularly effective weapon when dealing with multiple targets, but it does have a serious cool factor.